# Why Rails session is being shared between multiple users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication

I am trying to use session mechanism to store information of an user that is logged like this: **session[:user_id]=@user_id** , and that its ok.

But when a new user login in the app, the variable **session[:user_id]** is updated to the new user id, making the first one perform requests with an invalid id.

I used different browsers, private browsers, a browser in a Virtual Machine and another one in the host, and still got the problem.

I appreciate some suggestions. Is it normal the session being shared between multiple users? There is another way to store some specific data, and prevent the share between users? I thought that session was unique, why that variable is changing? The same happens for cookies variable.

**EDIT:**

application_controller

```
def sign_in
 if(password != "" && @user_id!= "" && jenkinsip != "")
   @client = JenkinsApi::Client.new(:server_url => jenkinsip, :username=> @user_id, :password=> password)
    if(@client.get_jenkins_version != nil)
      session[:user_id]=@user_id
    end
 end
end
```

in html

Comment: By default session doesn't share between multiple users (different browsers, pc, ...). If it does, there must be something wrong with your code. Please provide your code, where and how you use `session`

Comment: I think you use one session in one browser and only change the user credentials, right? If so, you should store such specific data in some manner avoiding sharing between these users, e.g. as a hash with keys of @user_id: `{ user1 => data1, user2 => data2 }`.

Comment: I tried with the code above with different browsers in a Virtual Machine and Host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time `session[:user_id]=@user_id` is called, the session[:user_id] is being set to whatever the @user_id variable is set as.

Try using`||=` instead of `=`

set the session with`session[:user_id]||= @user_id` to only set session[:user_id] to @user_id when session[:user_id] is undefined.

Comment: But this way session will be setted only for the first user, when session is undefined. The next users dont. am I wrong?

Comment: @koxta sessions are stored on the client side and set PER user, so what this mean is if a user already has an existing session, it won't set it again.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the excellent answer of **koxtra** and
also have a look on `devise` gem for the user authentication.

**Devise** will do everything for you like users signin, signup, creating sessions and many more functions. You have to only install the [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)
in your rails application.

Comment: As I show in the code, I am trying to use jenkins authentication system to login, to avoid the implementation of a new mechanism. So this gem can be adapted to this situation? or only for  Rails embed auth mechanisms?